# Breadcrumbs and struts 1.x

Tags: java, struts-1, breadcrumbs

How could I implement breadcrumbs with struts 1.x (for example when the user chooses a product browsing categories)?

Is there a plugin like [that](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-arianna-plugin/) for struts 1.x? Or?

**EDIT**

I'm trying to use [this](http://illumin-it.servehttp.com/wordpress/2012/06/how-to-make-an-easy-breadcrumb-in-java-for-mvc-framework/), but I'm not succeed in obtaining the right result.

I've 3 jsp pages (home, page1, page2). In all these pages, I've a sidebar menu (the same menu for all the pages) whose elements are retrieved from a db.

When the user clicks on a menu item, a servlet is called to retrieve the items which are sons of the choosen item and then a list of elements is displayed in the centre of page1.

From page1, by clicking on an item, another servlet is called to retrieve the items which are sons of the choosen item and then a list of elements is displayed in the centre of page2.

**EDIT**

I resolved. I had to add the node corresponding to the choosen item.

Answer (score 0):

I am somewhat new to Struts myself but this is how I have seen it being used with tiles at my work. The value "INQUIRY" becomes part of the breadcrumb.

```
<definition name="tile.view" extends=".layout">
    <put name="content" value="/search.jsp" />
    <put name="title.section" value="Inquiry"/>
    <putList name="breadcrumbs">
         <item link="/inquiry.do" value="INQUIRY"/>
    </putList>
</definition>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not using tiles.